varname.color in ggbiplot not being executed
I found that the code, which has been used in many examples, does not work anymore. While some time ago varname.color =  from the ggbiplot package outputted colored vectors in PCA biplots, the vectors (arrows) will now stay darkred even with the command being part of the code.
I found some rather complex solutions on SO (eg. writing a new function and using geom_segment()), however, there are many examples where this code has been working in the past, which made me question if there really is no more implemented solution for arrow color. Unfortunately, I haven't found any information on changes in the ggbiplot package, requiring new commands or current bugs.
Is there any way to change the arrow color in ggbiplot (v. 0.55)?
The following code outputs this:
PCA biplot with red arrows
But is explained to output this:
PCA biplot with black arrows - screenshot from cran.r
(The following code is a copy of a reproducible example from cran.r-project.org about ggbiplot)
iris.pca <- prcomp (~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
                    data=iris,
                    scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(iris.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
         groups = iris$Species, point.size=2,
         varname.size = 5, 
         varname.color = "black",
         varname.adjust = 1.2,
         ellipse = TRUE, 
         circle = TRUE) +
  labs(fill = "Species", color = "Species") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')


Your code works fine and gives the desired black arrows when using ggbiplot 0.6.2. Hence, if you are not restricted to an old version updating might be a fix.
